# Jquery Menu dropdown issue

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have this code and I am trying to make it so it will have a delay once you remove the mouse from the top menu item

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

  // Hover drop-downs
  $('#header_right li ul').stop().animate({"opacity":1}, "fast");
  $('#header_right li ul').stop().animate({"opacity":0}, "fast");


  $("#header_right ul > li").hover(function(){
    $(this).find("ul").css('display', 'block').stop().animate({"opacity":1}, "fast");
  }, function(){
    $(this).find("ul").css('display', 'none').stop().animate({"opacity":0}, "fast");
  });

});
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you considered the hoverIntent plugin? http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Answer (score 1):

Use **.delay()**

I assume you wanted to *delay* the hide (when mouse hover *out*)

Your code, I add **.delay(600)** on line 4. 600 is miliseconds.

```
$("#header_right ul > li").hover(function(){
  $(this).find("ul").css('display', 'block').stop().animate({"opacity":1}, "fast");
}, function(){
  $(this).find("ul").css('display', 'none').delay(600).stop().animate({"opacity":0}, "fast");
});
```

More info: http://api.jquery.com/delay/